# Laravel Eloquent relationship not working

Tags: php, mysql, web, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.4

I have two models User Model and Experience Model. I have created Experience method inside the User model like below.

```
public function Experience() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Experience', 'updatedbyuser_id');
}
```

Here updatedbyuser_id is the foreign key and is a column of the experiences table in the database.

I have created another method called User within the Experience model like below.

```
public function User() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

I have created a controller 'PagesController' and placed the below method in it

```
public function returnExperience() {
    $lists = Experience::where(['deleted' => '0'])->get();
    return view('pages.experience', compact('lists'));
}
```

To view the data returned by the returnExperience() method my view page has the below code

```
              @foreach($lists as $list)
                <tr>
                  <td>{{$list->min}}</td>
                  <td>{{$list->max}}</td>
                  <td>{{$list->grade}}</td>
                  <td>{{$list->User->id}}</td>
                  <td>{{$list->updated_at}}</td>
                  <td>Edit</td>
                </tr>
              @endforeach
```

but it returns the below error message on the screen

***Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo could not be converted to string***

Comment: first off all change the functions to different name other than the model name itself, then use $list->function_name()->id

Comment: @Exprater its completely fine to use $list->user->id as relations get automatically mapped to properties aswell. Unless you need to get methods from the relation then you would use user()->somemethod();

Answer (score 0):

did you try

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

and

```
          @foreach($lists as $list)
            <tr>
              <td>{{$list->min}}</td>
              <td>{{$list->max}}</td>
              <td>{{$list->grade}}</td>
              <td>{{$list->user->id}}</td>
              <td>{{$list->updated_at}}</td>
              <td>Edit</td>
            </tr>
          @endforeach
```

I think that functions should always start with lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

If a collection is cast to a string, it will be returned as JSON:

```
public function returnExperience() {
    $lists = (string) Experience::where(['deleted' => '0'])->get();
    return view('pages.experience', compact('lists'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of below line:

```
$list->User->id
```

try:

```
$list->User()->id
```

and always use camel casing while naming a function.